# is the Netlab's function mlperr calculating the mean squared error?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, mean-square-error

I wonder if the `mlperr` from the [Netlab package](http://www1.aston.ac.uk/eas/research/groups/ncrg/resources/netlab/) is calculating the mean squared error.
The [documentation](http://www.fizyka.umk.pl/netlab/mlperr.htm) states that it's dependent on the ouput's units activation function. How does that make sense? Shouldn't it be independent from that?

I also tried to read the [source code of `mlperr`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2654-netlab/content/mlperr.m) and I didn't see any signs that could make me think that this is a MSE error function.

Any Netlab expert here that can offer some insights? Thanks! :)

Comment: the source code clearly has a switch statement dependent on the output activation function: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2654-netlab/content/mlperr.m . In the linear function case, it is computing the formula of MSE indeed

Comment: I see, the problem is why? Shouldn't it just call the feedforward function and then calculating the mean square error via differences from output and target?

Comment: There are all kinds of [loss functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) one can use, not just MSE..

Comment: Using MSE for those activation functions is still correct? Isn't there a MSE function in Netlab to calculate the squared error even if I am using logistic?

Comment: As far I know, all combinations all correct. For example, if I remember correctly, training a perceptron can be equivalent to logistic regression when using a certain loss function (correct me if I'm wrong).. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_loss_functions.html) is a nice plot of various loss functions used in sklearn (a Python machine learning library).

Comment: So it's correct to use MSE to calculate the error on any type of network. But then why isn't Netlab providing this very common functionality? I can write the MSE function myself, of course...

Comment: truth is I havent used this package in a long time, but I think it should be possible to use your own error function if you want (preferably a convex one) :)

Answer (score 1):

This method is used to evaluate the multilayer perceptron accodring to its output activation. It assumes the most common usage of such, so:

- for linear output it returns the MSE error

  `0.5*sum(sum((y - t).^2))`
- for logistic output it returns the cross entropy error

  `-sum(sum(t.*log(y) + (1 - t).*log(1 - y)))`
- for softmax output it returns the corresponding energy error

  `-sum(sum(t.*log(y)))`

Whole source can be seen [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2654-netlab/content/mlperr.m).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why the MSE error in the linear output case is missing the averaging? Why is the sum function called twice?

Comment: `sum(sum(.))` because the variables are matrices. As for averaging, it is just dividing by a constant (number of instances), so it wont matter much..